# Nano can't unindent lines

Tags: nano, indentation

I can indent lines with: `Alt+}` but unindent doesn't work with `Alt+{` as it is supposed to work according to http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/sedwards/Nano/NanoKeyboardCommands.html.

I have added this keybinding line to the `/etc/nanorc`:

```
bind M-{ unindent main
```

also tried:

```
bind M-{ unindent all
```

But no success, what could be happening?

Comment: Are you using an international keyboard? It works fine for me using UK keyboard with no special settings in `/etc/nanorc`? If you type { at the command line do you see the expected symbol?

Comment: yes, and as I said, indentation works fine. Unindent is what doesn't work

Comment: works for me: does it not indent, or simply not show on the menu?

Comment: it does not indent, I'm using Kali Linux rolling